# Google Maps Engine and Google Maps Static API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating an application that displays maps using tiles. I am looking for a way to display content created on my Google Maps Engine account with this application. I found Google Maps Static API which is exactly what would work but have not found any information on if this will work with Google Maps Engine content. Is it possible to display GME content with the Static API?

Comment: Dan have you figured out if GME is supported?